# MS Access search each row in a table for a value in a macro

Tags: database, ms-access, macros

I am trying to write a macro for an inventory DB. Where as when on start up, this macro will run, and it will pop a message box up if an item quantity is lower then x. (and continue to popup for every item under that value until end of table)

I am fairly new to Access and am not really sure of the procedure of the macros.

Can anyone help me out on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a query which returns all inventory items whose quantity is less than your target minimum.

Then build a form based on that query.

Finally, set that new form as the applications's startup form.

With this approach, you wouldn't present the low-count items one at a time in separate message boxes.  So it may not match what you want.  See what your users prefer.